# Asp.net Repeater Checkbox ID and Value

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I would like to get the value and id of a checkbox in a repeater, and save the value in database. 
Here is what I have;

Repeater;

- I have an id like this ; <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%>">

the checkbox i want to use

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkRemind"  runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Check_Changed" AutoPostBack="true" />
```

code behind

```
    protected void Check_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

        I need to know the Id and find out the current checkbox value
        so i can do 

        UpdateDB(ID, checkboxValue);


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can databind the id to a data- attribute, then read that on postback.

`cb.Attributes["data-id"] = DataItem.ID;`

```
protected void Check_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

    var checkbox = sender as CheckBox;

    int ID = int.Parse(checkbox.Attributes["data-id"]);

    UpdateDB(ID, CheckBox.Checked);


}
```

Make sure you verify that the current user has permission to edit the requested item, since the data-id value can be changed on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
    protected void Check_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) {

    var item =  sender as Checkbox;

    UpdateDB(item.ID, item.Value);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable  `sender` contains Control, that triggered event, so you need just cast it to `CheckBox`

```
protected void Check_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   CheckBox chbSomeCheckbox = (CheckBox)sender;
   var ID = chbSomeCheckbox.ID;
   var checkboxValue = chbSomeCheckbox.Checked;

   UpdateDB(ID, checkboxValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is get sender control's ID

```
protected void Check_Changed(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Checkbox item =  sender as Checkbox;
    UpdateDB(item.ID, item.Value);
}
```